# how to change the color of text with different button in a listview items using flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi i'm wondering how to change text color of an item selected on a ListView ? I have a fragment who is a ListView and i wanted to change the color text when user click on button. I Tried something on  function
when user click buton1 the text color change to green other button for red and other button for orange. Can you help me please ?

Comment: It would be best to include some code, what you've tried, and maybe a small visual example of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like
Color _color = Colors.red
then in the onClick function you can use setstate tochange the color
setState({_color = Colors.blue})